# Access setup variables in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I am creating an app in nuxt 3 using vue 3 and vuetify 3.

Im trying to teach myself the new features of vue 3 having come from a heavy vue 2 background.

My code is as follows for a page. The code works but i cannot access the variable 'content' anywhere. You can see its in my template rendering out v-card, but if i use a normal  tag i cannot access content? i am getting content is undefined. Im aware they are in different script blocks, i guess im asking am i doing it wrong or can i access it easily?

```html
<script setup>
import { contentStore } from '@/stores/contentStore'
const setContentItem = contentStore();
const { pendingContent, content } = redisAggregateSearch('idx:content:details', '@deleted:0 @contentStatus:{Live} @contentArea:{Oomph TV}', '0', '20', '@id,@contentTitle,@contentAlias,@contentDescription,@thumbnailImageURL', '@contentTitle', false);

definePageMeta({
    name: 'Home',
    middleware: 'auth'
})

function openContent(item) {
    setContentItem.value = item
    navigateTo('/content/' + item.id)
}
</script>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        pageNo: 1,
        pageSize: 20,
    }),
    computed: {
        // numberOfPages() {
        //     debugger
        //     return Math.ceil(content.data.results / this.pageSize);
        // },
        // pagedContent() {
        //     let t = this;
        //     const startIndex = (t.pageNo - 1) * t.pageSize;
        //     const data = [...content];
        //     return data.splice(startIndex, t.pageSize);
        // }
    },
};
</script>

<template>
    <v-main>
        <v-container fluid>
            <app-bar />
            <v-row no-gutters>
                <div v-if="pendingContent" class="d-flex justify-center">
                    <v-progress-circular color="primary" :size="91" :width="10" indeterminate></v-progress-circular>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-center" v-else>
                    <v-col cols="12" class="pb-4">
                        <v-pagination v-model="pageNo" :length="numberOfPages" prev-icon="icons8-back-to"
                            next-icon="icons8-next-page" circle></v-pagination>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-card v-for="(item, index) in content.data.results" :key="index" @click="openContent(item)"
                        class="bg-primary elevation-0 pa-0 ma-2 mb-4 flex-wrap" width="280" height="200">
                        <v-card-title class="pa-0">
                            <v-img v-if="item.thumbnailImageURL" class="rounded" max-height="130"
                                :src="item.thumbnailImageURL" cover></v-img>
                            <v-img v-else class="rounded" max-height="130"></v-img>
                        </v-card-title>
                        <v-card-text class="pa-2">
                            <div class="text-body-2 font-weight-bold text-accent text-uppercase">
                                {{ item.contentAlias }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-body-2 font-weight-bold">
                                {{ item.contentTitle }}
                            </div>
                        </v-card-text>
                    </v-card>
                </div>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-main>
</template>
```

this is the redisAggregateSearch, ive removed the api url.

```js
export default (index, query, from, to, fields, sortBy, sortDesc) => {

    const { pending: pendingContent, data: content } = useLazyFetch(
        `${baseURL}/aggregatesearch/?index=${index}&searchquery=${query}&from=${from}&size=${to}&fields=${fields}&sortby=${sortBy}&sortdesc=${sortDesc}`
    );

    return {
        pendingContent,
        content,
    };
}
```

Comment: What does `redisAggregateSearch()` return?

Comment: Thanks for replying, its in composable and it just returns pendingContent and content in the return statement but using destructure in the useLazyFetch method, ill add it to the main question

Comment: You have AND script setup AND script, export default defineComponent. It's like you define two components in this file. Merge it to have only one. I would stringly suggest moving away from options api. Composables are much easier to work with with composition api.

Comment: `content` is initially undefined until the async API call is complete but the template is going to want to use it immediately causing your error.  don't render the v-card until it has a value

Comment: The template renders it fine, the redisAggregateSearch is complete and content is showing as i expect, its just when i want to manipulate that in a normal this.content situation i cant access it

Comment: ah, sorry I didn't notice the attempt to use content in the commented out code.  you can use `<script>` and `<script setup>` together ([docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script)) although this is not a good use case for it and no they can't share each others data.  you should be able to do everything you want with just script setup

Comment: Thanks ok @yoduh thanks for taking the time to reply! knowing they cant share each others data will explain my problem! ill try move it all to setup

Comment: Thanks @entio thats what i am trying to do, i didnt like the idea of having the two script blocks. But i cannot manipulate content still even if its in one <script setup> block. Which leads me to ask, do i have to do something in my composable redisAggregateSearch or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer to this was to split out the v-card content section into its own component and pass the data down as a prop, upon the component mounting i was able to hook into computed and manipulate the data as per vue.js examples:

[Vue grid example](https://vuejs.org/examples/#grid)